# Need the next milestone number for the number provided

Tags: javascript, java

I am not sure how to frame this question. Let me give a few scenarios to explain what I need.

Scenario 1:

I provide number as 9600 and I want to be returned 10000

Scenario 2:

I provide number as 98700 and I want to be returned 100000

Scenario 3:

I provide number as 196000 and I want to be returned 200000

This is what I exactly want. Either Java or Javascript solutions are fine. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far? What is your question?

Comment: @ChrisStarling As I said I am not sure how to frame this question. I ll try to convey. Basically I want the next highest milestone number (if I can say so) for the number which I provide. I was thinking but couldn't think of a logic to do this. Thanks for the prompt reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need logarithms for that:

Javascript:

```
var base = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(number)/Math.log(10)));
var milestone = Math.ceil(number / base) * base;
```

where `number` is your number provided and `milestone` is the result you want to get.

What happens here:

- At first we calculate the `base`, it's the largest power of 10 smaller than `number`, so it contains as many digits as your number does. This is done calculating the base-10 logarithm of our number *(log(n)/log(10))* and taking the result as the power of 10. For 4521 for example that would be 1000
- After that, we divide our number by that base and round up to the next full integer, so 4521 / 1000 = 4.521, rounded up makes 5
- Then, we multiply that with the base again and get the result 5000

Comment: Hey it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot :) Accepting the answer right away

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(final String... args) {
      final int number = 98000;
      final int mult = (int) Math.pow(10, String.valueOf(number).length() - 1);

      System.out.println((number + mult - 1) / mult * mult);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let value=19600;
let rounded = Math.ceil(value/100000)*100000;
console.log(rounded);
```

Comment: it's a bad question because he has not fathomed the problem, this answer helps him frame the problem so he can begin to solve it...ahh it is a rounding problem!! not a "next milestone" problem there is no Math.nextMilestone(). I have been there, not knowing what to ask. this is a push.

Comment: So then it would be worth a comment, but it is not an answer to the question

Comment: Perhaps, but he really needed help framing the question. I did that. The accepted answer coded the solution for him. ehh. whatever.

Comment: And explained what it does, for understanding ;) But that's what this site is for: Answering questions, not pushing someone to the right way. If anybody else gets a similar problem, the solution can be found on Stack Overflow. That's exactly what is wanted.

Comment: Fine, got it!!! SO is soo finicky. Sometimes you all are like "Show your work!" "learn to ask questions" "I am not programming for you", blah blah. Other time this. Guy does not even ask a real question and POP! out comes full code! LOL!  In my defense: from the poster: "I am not sure how to frame this question..... Any help would be much appreciated" I gave him help that helped him frame the question.

Comment: I'll admit that had i given him full code it would have been a shitty answer because I was thinking "if" statements. The accepted answer nailed it. I'll know better next time.

Comment: There is a difference between "I need a small piece of code because there must be a way I don't see yet" and "Please write a whole software for me". To a mathematical problem, the access is much more subtile than to a problem like "why is my code not working". In seeing a question like the current one, you can assume that the author made some research on his own, while when seeing a question like "why is my printf(31) failing", you know that the author not even bothered reading the f***ng manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
public long milestone(long original) {
   String strNumber = String.valueOf(original);
   long result = strNumber.charAt(0) + '1';
   for (int i=1; i<strNumber.length(); i++)
      result *= 10;
   return result;
}
```

I am not sure about what you need, but this code cover your examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer is conceptually the best possible.

If for some reason you would need to make a lot of milestone calculations and performance would be an issue (this is all purely hypothetical), you could cache the milestones to reduce the calculation overhead as follows:

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MilestoneUtil {
    private static final SortedSet<Long> MILESTONES;

    static {
        MILESTONES = new TreeSet<>();
        long base = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < String.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE).length(); i++) {
            MILESTONES.add(base);
            MILESTONES.add(2*base);
            MILESTONES.add(3*base);
            MILESTONES.add(4*base);
            MILESTONES.add(5*base);
            MILESTONES.add(6*base);
            MILESTONES.add(7*base);
            MILESTONES.add(8*base);
            MILESTONES.add(9*base);
            base *= 10;
        }
    }

    public static long nextMilestone(long current) {
        return MILESTONES.tailSet(current).first();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMilestone(9600);
        printMilestone(98700);
        printMilestone(196000);
    }

    private static void printMilestone(long input) {
        System.out.println(String.format("The next milestone for %d is: %d", input, nextMilestone(input)));
    }
}
```